# Upload Multipart and JSON object from Angular 12 to SpringBoot REST Service

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have to invoke a REST service in SpringBoot using a REST service in POST that sends a JSON object and a JPG file, but when i make the call i receive this error.

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

The front-end application is Angular 12 and back-end is Spring Boot.

this is my FE code

```
  public inserisciArticolo(articolo : any): Observable<any>{
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }) };
    //return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.REST_API_SERVER + "/addArticolo",anagrafica, httpOptions);
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    
        formData.append('file', articolo.foto);
        formData.append('articolo', articolo);
    
        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.REST_API_SERVER + "/addArticolo", formData, {
          reportProgress: true,
          responseType: 'json'
        });
    
        //return this.httpClient.request(req);
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.REST_API_SERVER + "/addArticolo",formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

this is the BE code

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/addArticolo", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE  })
    public Response addArticolo(@RequestPart ArticoloDTO articolo,@RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        logger.info("addArticolo -START- {}",articolo.toString());
        Response response = service.addArticolo(articolo);
        logger.info("addArticolo -END-");
        return response;
    }
```